# Can NFC in nexus mobile read ordinary RFID tag?

Tags: nfc, rfid

Can NFC in nexus s mobile can read ordinary RFID tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been many different RFID tags over the years and the Nexus S does not read them all. In particular the reader in the Nexus S can read many of what are called HF (high frequency) tags. It cannot read UHF (ultra high frequency) tags. Do you know the technology used in what you're referring to as 'ordinary' RFID tags?

Comment: which RFID tag can read/write by NFC, and can we encrypt data in RFID tag, basically i want secure communication between RFID tag and NFC.Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

Check out the NFC documentation at the android development docs, you'll find all supported formats.
In short words:
The Nexus android phones can read and write most NFC tags available.

I was even able to communicate with german passports, at least to that part where the encryption starts.

The ordinary RFID tags you may find on some products or in access-regulated areas can mostly be read but you'll need a lot of code and experience.
Each ISO protocol is different and on top of it each single chip is different, you need to write unique code for each CHIP manufacturer to support reading and writing because those commands are not part of the core-iso specification.
At least not in ISO 14443 or 15693